# How to map quadratic programming formulation to dual soft margin SVM

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, quadratic-programming

I am trying to use quadratic programming for SVM and I am confused about how to map SVM formulation to quadratic programming formulation given in CVXOPT (Python package). 
This is what CVXOPT gives us

[image]

This is what I need to map (dual soft margin support vector machine formulation):

[image]

Can someone explain how those two map..?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CVXOPT software solves quadratic programs of the form
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min\ & \frac{1}{2}x^TPx+q^Tx \\
\text{s.t.}\ & Gx\leq h \\
& Ax=b
\end{array}
$$

The problem you wish to solve is 
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\max\ & \sum_i\alpha_i-\frac{1}{2}\big\|\sum_i\alpha_iy_ix_i\big\|^2 \\
\text{s.t.} & -\alpha_i\leq0\text{ for all }i \\
& \alpha_i\leq{C}\text{ for all }i \\
& \sum_iy_i\alpha_i=0
\end{array}
$$

I'm assuming here $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$ are vectors and $y_i\in\mathbb{R}$ are scalars for $i=1,\dots,n$.

**Objective Function**

Let's look at the expression

$$\bigg\|\sum_i\alpha_iy_ix_i\bigg\|^2.$$

Let's define the vector $z_i=y_ix_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$. Define the matrix $Z\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times{n}}$ to be the matrix whose $i^\text{th}$ column is $z_i$. Then the expression above can be written as

$$
\|Z\alpha\|^2=\alpha^TZ^TZ\alpha
$$

where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the vector of $\alpha_i$ variables, and we are using the two norm.

Hence our objective function is

$$\max\ \sum_i\alpha_i-\frac{1}{2}\bigg\|\sum_i\alpha_iy_ix_i\bigg\|^2=\max\ -\frac{1}{2}\alpha^TZ^TZ\alpha+\mathbf{1}^T\alpha=\min\ \frac{1}{2}\alpha^TZ^TZ\alpha-\mathbf{1}^T\alpha$$

where $\mathbf{1}$ is the vector of all ones. This is exactly the form required by CVXOPT: take $P=Z^TZ$ and $q=-\mathbf{1}$.

**Inequality Constraints**

The constraints $-\alpha_i\leq0$ can be written as

$$
-I\alpha\leq\mathbf{0}
$$

where $I$ is the $n\times{n}$ identity matrix, and $\mathbf{0}$ is the zero vector. Similarly, the constraints $\alpha_i\leq{C}$ can be written in matrix form as

$$
I\alpha\leq C\mathbf{1}.
$$

If we stack these two matrix systems on top of each other, then our inequality constraints can be summarized as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-I\\I\end{bmatrix}\alpha\leq\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{0}\\C\mathbf{1}\end{bmatrix}.
$$

This is the form required by CVXOPT: take

$$
G=\begin{bmatrix}-I\\I\end{bmatrix},\ h=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{0}\\C\mathbf{1}\end{bmatrix}.
$$

**Equality Constraints**

I think you can take it from here.

Once you have all these matrices and vectors created, just pass them to `solvers.qp()` and you should be good to go.